# System.Drawing.Graphings.SmoothingMode getter throws ArgumentException "Parameter is not valid"

Tags: c#, gdi, system.drawing, dotnetbar

I have a large and resource intensive C# GUI application which uses the [DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/) 3rd party UI library.

Occasionally, it fails with the following exception and call stack:

```
====================================
 ERROR 
====================================
Exception type: ArgumentException
Parameter is not valid.

====================================
 CALL STACK 
====================================
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.get_SmoothingMode()
   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.⍜.PaintCaptionBackground(FormCaptionRendererEventArgs e)
   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.Rendering.Office2007Renderer.DrawFormCaptionBackground(FormCaptionRendererEventArgs e)
   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.OfficeForm.ὀ(Graphics ٠)
   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.OfficeForm.ᲀ()
   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.OfficeForm.WindowsMessageNCActivate(Message& m)
   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.RibbonForm.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The call which is failing at the top of the stack is just accessing the [SmoothingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode?view=netframework-4.7.2) property, and property getters have no parameters, so it's a bit hard to know that the "Parameter is not valid" could mean.

This exception happens sporadically, it's not reproducible 100% of the time, but does seem to be associated with high resource usage within my application (it happens on loading a particular large "project" into the application) whereas other smaller projects do not trigger this, even though both large and small projects use the DotNetBar UI in the same way.

What would cause the `SmoothingMode` property to throw an ArgumentException?

Comment: How many GDI Objects are active after your app opens a large project?  Task Manager (More Details) - Details Tab - right mouse click header - Select Columns - GDI Objects.

Comment: @LarsTech I did suspect GDI object leakage, but according to task man, it's at about 480 after loading the large project.   Which is substantially lower than the number that outlook.exe or devenv.exe are using, so that seems OK.  I think I read somewhere a limit of about 10k per application on those.

Comment: SmoothingMode can throw an ArgumentException for a number of reasons. In this case, it looks like the call to the native gdiplus.dll method `GdipGetSmoothingMode` is returning a status of 2. The only parameter being passed in is a `HandleRef` struct created with the graphics `NativeGraphics` pointer. That's about as far as I can dive into this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this, it turned out to be a case where object that owns the `System.Drawing.Graphics` object had been disposed.

In the DotNetBar library, `DotNetBar.BufferedBitmap` objects which are doing some low-level calls to allocate a bitmap, and then returning the Graphics using `Graphics.FromHdc(IntPtr)`.  If the `BufferedBitmap` was disposed before use, then all of the properties on the `Graphics` object would throw an exception when you try to access them.

The reason why the bitmap was being disposed before being used was complicated and a result of the interaction of my application with DotNetBar.  In a nutshell:  a `WM_NCACTIVATE` message triggered some code to redraw the window caption, but this caption-drawing code was triggering an OnPaint in my application, and indirectly triggering a WndProc that was processing another `WM_NCACTIVATE`, and thus calling the caption-drawing code underneath itself.  One level of caption-drawing code was disposing the bitmap that the other level was not finished using.